# JavaScript RegularExpression asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to RegularExpression in **asp.net MVC 2**. It's been whole day looking for the right syntax trial and error.

If anyone could help?

Here is the problem:

**minimum hours work/day -> allowable float number but not greater than 24**

**minimum hours work/week -> allowable float number but not greater than 56**

---

I'm trying to create regex that will accept if the input is integer or float number but not greater than 24.

Also if the input has white space print `ErrorMessage = " White space is not allowed"`

---

**VIEW**

```
<td>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dblMinHrs, new { @class = "txtInput"})%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dblMinHrs)%>
</td>

<td>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dblMinWk, new { @class = "txtInput"})%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dblMinWk)%>
</td>
```

---

**MODEL**

```
[RegularExpression("([0-1]\\d{0,1})|(2[0-4])", ErrorMessage = "Must not greater than 24")]
  public double dblMinHrs { get; set; }


  [RegularExpression("([0-4]\d{0,1})|(5[0-6])", ErrorMessage = "Must not greater than 24")]
  public double dblMinWk { get; set; }
```

Anyone please help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should post examples of the code that you wrote that pertains to your question. A good example would be the regex pattern you're using and how you're using it in javascript.

Comment: I posted the sample codes above Sir. Thank You very much

Answer (score 1):

check this...

```
regex for minimum work/day -> /([0-1]\d{0,1})|(2[0-4])/
regex for minimum work/week -> /([0-4]\d{0,1})|(5[0-6])/
```

Comment: [RegularExpression("/([0-1]\d{0,1})|(2[0-4])/", ErrorMessage = "Must not greater than 24")]                                                        
public double dblMinHrs { get; set; }    | my visual studio encounter runtime error

Comment: Remove the '/' at the beginning and end. And you probably need to escape the '\', try '\\'.

Comment: Anyone please help. Thanks in advance god bless.